# Tensorflow/nmt: How to get the encoder hidden states?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, machine-translation

I have just started to work with tensorflow. I'm following the tutorial on neural machine translation given by Thang Luong, Eugene Brevdo, Rui Zhao here

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq

I want to use the model as an auto-encoder but I was wondering how we can get the encoder hidden states at inference time?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [dynamic encoder architecture defined in the NMT tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt#encoder):

```
# Build RNN cell
encoder_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units)

# Run Dynamic RNN
#   encoder_outputs: [max_time, batch_size, num_units]
#   encoder_state: [batch_size, num_units]
encoder_outputs, encoder_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    encoder_cell, encoder_emb_inp,
sequence_length=source_sequence_length, time_major=True)
```

Then doing a `sess.run([encoder_state], feed_dict={...})[0]` will return the encoder hidden state of the *final* node. If you want states from *all* of the nodes, I would refer to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272567/how-to-extract-the-cell-state-and-hidden-state-from-an-rnn-model-in-tensorflow).